# Which word is correct word in that situation?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, nouns, legalese, past-participles

What word should I use in that situation? "right", "entitle", "title" or other word? I don't want use "can".

> If you have driver license, you have.... to drive a car.

Comment: Clarify it more. Where you want to use the word? Which way right, entitle, or title fits?

Comment: I want to say like this: You need a driver license to entitle  drive a car.

Comment: I want to say about taking a privilege to drive a car.

Comment: Note that it should be "[driver's license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_license)" or "driving license". Also, in British English, the second word is spelled "[licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_licence_in_the_United_Kingdom)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have driver license you are entitled to drive a car. 
You also may use some of the following constructions: you have the right, you may, you are able to, you are allowed to, you are permitted to, etc. depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have **a** driver's license, you have the **privilege** of driving a car.

In the United States, driving cars on public roads is a privilege, not a right.  A driver's license grants this legal privilege.  A driver's license can lapse, be suspended, or be revoked.